# Looking for multiple strings from txt file with simple_html_dom, only displays last

Tags: php

I have a text file with 3 sentences from a URL, two sentences are present.
No matter what i do, this code always just shows the last variable from the textfile. It looks exactly as what we need, but we need it forevery word/sentence.

Played for hours, cannot get it to work. Who can point me in the right direction?

[php]

```
$url = "http://www.".$_GET['u']; //"example.com/";
$lines = file("all_claims.txt");

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_for_text($iUrl,$iText)
{
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($iUrl);

    // get text elements
    $aObj = $html->find('text');
    foreach ($aObj as $key=>$seString)
    {
      $plaintext = $seString->plaintext;
      if (stripos($plaintext,$iText) !== FALSE)
      {
         echo "<b>".$iText."</b><br />";
         echo $key.": text=".$plaintext."<br />"
              ."--- parent tag=".$seString->parent()->tag."<br />";
      }

    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return;
}

ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    echo $line."<br />";
    scraping_for_text($url,$line);
}
```

[/php]

I would really appreciate the help.

KK.

Comment: Could you show your simple_`html_dom.php` and `all_claims.txt`?

Comment: simpledom is downloaded from sourceforge i believe, standard package.
The textfile is just three word(group)s. nothing fancy. Each entry on a new line

The issue seems to be in this section: foreach ($aObj as $key=>$seString)